# Problema geolocalizacion en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, geolocalización

tengo un problema con el plugin `Geolocator` me da el error del autorizacion de la fotos:

Éste es el **codigo xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             x:Class="Test.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label x:Name="Lat"  Text="Latitud" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="Long"  Text="Logitud" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Button x:Name ="TestB"  
          Text="Hola"  
          Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

---

Éste es el **código c#**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();

            Lat.Text = "Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
            Long.Text = "Longitude: " + position.Longitude.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Manifest**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cXSp.jpg]

---

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que veo estas utilizando Xamarin Forms. Esto te pasa solo en Android o en UWP y iOS también te sale este error?

Comment: Solo lo estoy haciendo para android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegurate que el método OnCreate del MainActivity.cs realice el registro del Plugin CrossCurrentActivity, de la siguiente forma:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{            
    // Código de tu clase
    // ............

    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Init(this, bundle);

    // Código de tu clase
    // ............
}
```

Luego adiciona el siguiente código al archivo AssemblyInfo.cs de tu proyecto de Android:

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.gps", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.location.network", Required = false)]
```

Adicionalmente este plugin necesita establecer permisos sobreescribiendo el siguiente método en tu MainActivity.cs dentro del proyecto  de Android:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Tomado de las ayudas de github:  https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Me dice que el activity no Continente la definicion init.

Comment: OK. entonces intenta con esto:
`protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
}`

Comment: Gracias eso era!!!!! Me funciona en el emulador pero en mi samsung s8 no me da el permiso. Porque sera?